# Can't play Bobsled Bonanza on my iPod

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

This is the only minigame that causes the application to crash; however, this only happens with my username. If I use another username in the same device (i.e. my boyfriend's) he is able to play the game without the application being closed. 
Has anybody had this glitch? How did you fix it?

Comment: Your Username on Plants Vs. Zombies or on the whole iPad? What is the username in question? Have you tried creating a new PVZ username and seeing if it crashes on that as well?